# Removing individual datapoints from a scatter plot

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'm trying to remove anomalous data points in an excel scatter plot.
I currently have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6h3b.png). To me it's clear that there's a somewhat linear relationship in the red region, and several anomalous points in the blue region. I know it's obviously possible to remove these individually from the spreadsheet so they don't appear on the graph, but that will be very time consuming to find each of the offending points out of more than 240. Is there a way to remove them while looking at the chart itself, to exclude them from the calculation of any linear regression?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you believe your data are linear and want to remove points below the line, then you could arbitrarily determine where that line should cut your data and use a formula to help you determine if the point falls above or below the line.

Example: Let's pretend your linear formula is

```
y=-0.2x - 66
```

Then in your data, create a helper column and use a formula like this:

```
Cell C2 formula: =IF((-0.2*A2)-66<=B2,"Above","Below")
```

Drag it down, then sort your data and remove the "Belows".

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked :)

Comment: @Cm922 Very cool, if this resolves your question, then please consider marking as approved, thanks.